# Behavior of ngModel in Angular2

Tags: angular2-forms

I'm new to Angular2 and not able to explain the behavior observed where a change in an input form of one browser shows up immediately on a different one (even on a different device) showing the same page. What exactly is my "model" in this case?
And how is communication done from Client->Server->Clients, is this through an opened WebSocket? What server component is "forwarding" the changes?

"parameters" here is an array of {name, {value,unit}} retrieved through an http.get call.

```
                <li *ngFor="let parameter of parameters">
                    <div>
                    <label>{{parameter[0]}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text"  class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]='parameter[1][0]'>
                </li>
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you using angular 2 with meteor ?

Comment: I'm using it with Node.js